# Tagging the the map with comment and photo in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I have an application in iPhone in which I am now playing with MKMapView. However, I am getting stuck at one place, and it's hard for me to find a solution for this.

I am stuck at tagging the Map with Photos and making comment on that location and on the photo. How can this possible to do? I think it's like drop annotation the map; it must display the map with photos and comment if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need check MKAnnotationView. It's a custom AnnotationView who Inherits from UIView.
[MKAnnotationView Class Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: but , i am having one doubt if i click particular photo how could that photo image saved on annotation pin.

Comment: @Rani I don't know if it's what you want, but this pictures show what you can do [Demo MKAnnotationView](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_tlKMYGUFGPs/TSsrZxA4SjI/AAAAAAAAAZ8/BEQpIYwd4to/s320/IMG_0169.png)